# Want to prevent SCORM Terminate() to refresh browser when using adl.nav.request(target="")

Tags: flash, flex4, scorm2004

That is my first topic here.i hope you can help me.
I don't know if anyone knows Scorm but it  is a standard for e-learning porposes.

I have got a flex app that communicates with a Scorm-API.
When i run a javascript function from flex with "adl.nav.request" , i have to make a terminate function to make it happen which unloads the whole system,becouse this function updateds an "imsmanifest.xml" file. This xml is updated this time. This xml contains all the items that are connected to the index.hml which runs the flex app. That is why its refreshes. But i don't want my flex application to restart too.

How can i do that?
Is anybody a scorm expert?:)

Good bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of strange things in your question. First, terminating the connection with the LMS while still actively in the course. Second, updating the IMSMANIFEST.XML that should remain static. Third, calling for a adl.nav.request between SCOs when you want to remain on the same SCO and retain the current Flex app content.

It sounds like what you really want is a single SCO course (only one organization node in the imsmanifest.xml file). For a single SCO course, Terminate usually only happens at the end after completion and success status have updated or if the course makes use of an internal Exit/Quit button. Is there a requirement for the course to use Sequencing and Navigation?

Comment: Matt thank you for your answer. In update i mean call the adl.nav.request targeting another item.i should have to be able to make a scorm 2004 3th edition course with all the avalible cmi elements. I wanted to make some tricky solvation with keeping the flex app unrefreshed while i jump to another item. The rusticy scorm app documentation says that every ald.nav.request example continue should follow terminate. Thats why i want to do something to keep my flex up unrefreshed while the item change is executed(when the main window is flickers by the wrapper js . My english is so pure matt. Sry if

Answer (score 1):

Termination takes place when the user goes away from the current activity to another one. In fact the LMS receives the termination request from your SCO when it is unloaded from the browser. You cannot keep two activities active at the same time. One activity ONLY must be active at any time. 
It is not clear what you mean by "unrefreshed".

Comment: Thank You Fadel for your message!
Unrefreshed means, that the Flex content won't refresh wen this terminate happens and the application remains active on its currentState, no reloading etc.:)

Comment: Mate, this is not possible since termination is followed by loading new content.

Comment: Our software is working like this.it's opening in a new window. On the main index.html a flash content runs, this page opens a popup window with the flex course ap. The two swf communicates with localconnection. The first one in the index.html sends the data to lms like an engine, the other is the player. I am so sad about this becouse i would be able to make sutch great lessons. Planed to comebined it with the new alternativa3d engine.

Comment: Maybe you are not using the right tool for what you want to do. Have a look at this website, http://www.naseelco.com . They have some tools which create 100% SCORM compliant courses.